# How to refactor this code to combine several sections?

Tags: c#, console, refactoring, calculator

Let's say I have these 3 not so different codes.

How can I combine them, or let's just say I want to enter 10 numbers once I open the application.

I want those numbers to be added to each other, and at the same time show me if the number is even or not.

Here is the input code:

```
int[] dizi = new int[10]; 
for (int i=0; i<=10; i++)
{
    dizi[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Here is the addition code:

```
int[] dizi[i] 
int toplam=0;  
foreach(int sayi in dizi)  
{  
    toplam=toplam+sayi;  
}  
Console.WriteLine("Dizideki sayıların toplamı = " + toplam);
```

Here is the even number code:

```
int[] dizi[i] 
int toplam=0;  

foreach(int sayi in dizi)  
{  
    if (sayi%2 ==0)  
    Console.WriteLine(sayi);  
}
```

Comment: sorry forgot to delete that one the question wasn't good enough I will delete it at once! this one is the on I need it.

Comment: @OlivierRogier yes thank you for your consideration I couldn't post with my other account so I had to create another one. I tried to fix the question for better and it will really help me if you let this question stay longer I really can't find anything so I need this question to be answered. Thanks again

Comment: Thank you so much! I will look into it and if I find the answer I will delete or post the answer under here so someone who has the same issue can get help from me. @OlivierRogier

Comment: @OlivierRogier yes thank you I already deleted it and the question is better thanks for your help again.

Comment: <= would make the for loop iterate 11 times instead of 10, as the index begins at 0.

Answer (score 0):

All code in one for loop.
For input 10 elements you need `for` from `0` to `i < array.Length`
because array `int[10]` access by index from `0` to `9`

```
var array = new int[10];
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    var number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    sum += number;
    if (number % 2 == 0)
        Console.WriteLine($"The number {number} is even");
}
Console.WriteLine($"Sum = {sum}");
```